# Solving a differential involving Dirac-Delta function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this equation:
$$\frac{{\rm d^2}\psi(x)}{{\rm d}x^2}+\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}(E+V_0\delta(x))\psi(x)=0$$
here $E<0$ and $V_0>0$. This equation is for finding wave function of a particle under attractive delta potential.

I can easily solve for $x\ne0$. The boundary conditions are $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\psi(x)=0$

Comment: Do you know how to apply the Fourier Transform to a differential equation?

Comment: @Paul no, not yet.

Comment: You find this in $EVERY$ book on quantum mechanics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate both sides of the equation between $-\epsilon$ and $+\epsilon$ and then let $\epsilon\to 0$. Under assumption that $\psi$ remains continuous at $x=0$, this will lead (show it!) to 
$$\psi'(0^+)-\psi'(0^-)+\frac{2mV_0}{\hbar^2}\psi(0)=0.$$
More details can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_potential#Solving_the_Schr.C3.B6dinger_equation).